# How to replace a column in a row with the next row having specific condition on that column in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, replace

I am trying to apply a function to all rows of a dataframe. I basically want to check different conditions in columns 1 and 2 of a row and try to replace the value of column 3 with the value of column 3 in next row which has a specific condition.  I have been trying to figure out how to do so but unfortunately no luck so far. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

My data are like this:

```
    Col1         col2    col3    
    duty           1       0
    duty           0       0     
    inspection     0       0
    inspection     0
```

For each row that has col1 as "duty" and col2==1, if col1=="inspection" in the next row, I want to pu col3==1. Otherwise, I want this to be zero. In the data provided above, row 1 is the only row having the conditions, however, col1!="inspection" in the next row so col3==0. However, if the data was as follow:

```
    Col1         col2    col3    
    duty           1       0
    duty           1       1     
    inspection     0       0
    inspection     0
```

Then row two meets all conditions and col3==1 for that row.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of what you have, the conditions you want to compare and the output you are looking for?

Comment: I just edited the whole thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your reproducible data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("duty","duty","inspection","inspection"),
             col2=c(1,0,0,0),
             col3=c(0,0,0,0),
             stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- data.frame(col1=c("duty","duty","inspection","inspection"),
             col2=c(1,1,0,0),
             col3=c(0,1,0,0),
             stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Use this function, which uses `dplyr::lag` to compare `i-1`th row

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(df) {
              df$col3[with(df, which(col1=="inspection" & lag(col2,default=NA)==1 & lag(col1,default=NA)=="duty"))] <- 1
              return(df)
         }
```

#### Output

```
myfun(df1)

        col1 col2 col3
1       duty    1    0
2       duty    0    0
3 inspection    0    0
4 inspection    0    0

myfun(df2)

        col1 col2 col3
1       duty    1    0
2       duty    1    1
3 inspection    0    1
4 inspection    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I figured out to do it in a different way but your solution seems shorter.